# How do I Parent a Camera to a Empty with only one axis as a constraint?

Tags: animation, rigging, 3d-view, camera, empty

[image]

As you can see in the above example, the create parent with transform is making the camera move in all the rotation and location keys, I want the camera to move only specifically for the Z axis of the Empty... How do I achieve this>?

Comment: So maybe a Copy Location with only the Z axis activated?

Comment: Or you can use a driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenting will always copy all transforms. As Moonboots commented, you can use a [Copy Location constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_location.html) to only copy some transforms.